# User does not have access to Content Editor in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

User has only Page Editor access. I tried adding different roles to the user but it still does not work. The only way to give user access to Content Editor is set him up as admin and i do not really want to give admin rights to the user.

Comment: There is tons of documentation available on how to set up security in Sitecore CMS. Please read this carefully.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to assign the standard role `Sitecore\Author` to your acount. See the [Sitecore security reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20Reference.aspx) for more details.

Comment: what about if we don't need to give any write access. Author role seems to have write access to media library folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below roles manually for the user whom you want to be a content author.

- Sitecore\Developer
- Sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing
- Sitecore\Designer
- Sitecore\Author
- Sitecore\Sitecore Client Users

For more information please refer to this post - [roles required for a content author](http://www.kewlcodes.com/posts/112/How-to-create-a-new-login-user-in-Sitecore-and-what-are-roles-required-for-a-content-author)